# Prevent device orientation changes for specific screens and force "portrait"?

Tags: dart, flutter, orientation

In my flutter application, i want to set **portrait** orientation for only selected screens.

Code:

```
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
        DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
        DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
      ]);
```

Above code works fine until i visit to screen where i have set the orientation in build method. But i come back from that screen, the whole app orientation locks to "portrait" mode.